# Apache reverse proxy not working over SSL

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQUoq.png)

I have configured apache reverse proxy on my ubuntu machine. My application url is `http://unaeem-test.xavor.com/Agile`.

I set servername (`unaeem-agile.xavor.com`) under virtual host with port 80. Everything works fine: I browse url `http://unaeem-agile.xavor.com/Agile` and it takes me to my application.

Once I configure SSL then things doesn't work the same way: I am able to open `https://unaeem-agile.xavor.com` (it shows apache page) but `https://unaeem-agile.xavor.com/Agile` doesn't work and it takes me to `http://unaeem-agile.xavor.com/Agile`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzNhJ.png)

Please let me know what I missing

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: ...and, on top: This question is not programming related. Please also read [help/on-topic] and either edit it to be on-topic, or find a better place in the stackexchange network.